# finding max date of consecutive zero in int comp column

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to calculate max date of consecutive zero in PRIN COMP column. In end date column the date should be max date of consecutive zero. I tried using rank function but not able to get that max date

```
AGREEMENTID DUEDATE                 PRINCOMP    INTCOMP END_DATE
267        15FEB2017:00:00:00.000   0           46411   
267        15MAR2017:00:00:00.000   32258       64167   
267        15APR2017:00:00:00.000   32554       63871   
267        15MAY2017:00:00:00.000   32852       63573   
267        16AUG2019:00:00:00.000   34521       61904   
267        16SEP2019:00:00:00.000   0           56912   
267        15OCT2019:00:00:00.000   0           51612   
267        15NOV2019:00:00:00.000   0           53333   
267        16DEC2019:00:00:00.000   0           51612   
267        15JAN2020:00:00:00.000   0           53333   
267        15FEB2020:00:00:00.000   0           53333   15FEB2020:00:00:00.000
267        15AUG2029:00:00:00.000   82334       3491    
267        15SEP2029:00:00:00.000   83109       2716    
267        15OCT2029:00:00:00.000   83892       1933    
267        15NOV2029:00:00:00.000   84682       1143    
267        15DEC2029:00:00:00.000   36691       346
```

Comment: How many zeros constitutes a run of consequtive zeros? You have zero in you first line, but no value for END_DATE?

Comment: if consecutive zero are more than 2 times then it should take the last date of consecutive zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data have;
   infile cards firstobs=2;
   input id date:datetime. princomp intcomp;
   format date datetime.;
   cards;
AGREEMENTID DUEDATE                 PRINCOMP    INTCOMP END_DATE
267        15FEB2017:00:00:00.000   0           46411   
267        15MAR2017:00:00:00.000   32258       64167   
267        15APR2017:00:00:00.000   32554       63871   
267        15MAY2017:00:00:00.000   32852       63573   
267        16AUG2019:00:00:00.000   34521       61904   
267        16SEP2019:00:00:00.000   0           56912   
267        15OCT2019:00:00:00.000   0           51612   
267        15NOV2019:00:00:00.000   0           53333   
267        16DEC2019:00:00:00.000   0           51612   
267        15JAN2020:00:00:00.000   0           53333   
267        15FEB2020:00:00:00.000   0           53333   15FEB2020:00:00:00.000
267        15AUG2029:00:00:00.000   82334       3491    
267        15SEP2029:00:00:00.000   83109       2716    
267        15OCT2029:00:00:00.000   83892       1933    
267        15NOV2029:00:00:00.000   84682       1143    
267        15DEC2029:00:00:00.000   36691       346 
;;;;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   set have;
   by id princomp notsorted;
   if princomp eq 0 then do;
      if first.princomp then c=0;
      c+1;
      if c gt 2 then do;
         if last.princomp and not first.princomp then edate = date;
         end;
      end;
   format edate datetime.;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: It works .. but why its creating other values in "c" column for Non zero princomp

Comment: You can drop C.